# How do you edit nginx config in Security Onion 2?

Tags: nginx

I need to set some `nginx.conf` values for my [Security Onion 2](https://docs.securityonion.net/en/latest/about.html) install due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895933/nginx-emerg-could-not-build-the-server-names-hash-you-should-increase-server), but nginx runs inside docker.

Where can I update nginx config values?

I've run `locate nginx.conf` but none of the results (eg `/securityonion/salt/nginx/etc/nginx.conf`, `/source/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`) seem to do anything after editing them and running `sudo so-nginx-restart`.

Answer (score 0):

The correct nginx.conf file to edit wasn't appearing in my locate command, it turned out to be in:

```
/opt/so/saltstack/default/salt/nginx/etc/nginx.conf
```

After editing that file, you can apply the changes using `sudo so-nginx-restart`.